# how to Find the Mount Path of Pendrive in better way?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, embedded-linux

I have a requirement like . My Embedded system consist of program which on start up looks for a pendrive and specific directory in pendrive. if the directories are found its considered as bootable device.

Consider Below code :

```
uint8 Check_BB_rootfs_Availability()
{

    uint8 b_flag = 0x00;

    dw_PkgAvailFlag |= BB_PKG_AVAIL_MASK;

    if(!(system("ls /media1/sda/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/")))
    {
        path_argv[0] = "/media1/sda/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/rootfs.ubifs";
    }
    else if(!(system("ls /media1/sda1/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/")))
    {
        path_argv[0] = "/media1/sda/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/rootfs.ubifs";
    }
    else if(!(system("ls /media2/sda/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/")))
    {
        path_argv[0] = "/media2/sda/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/rootfs.ubifs";
    }
    else if(!(system("ls /media2/sda1/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/")))
    {
        path_argv[0] = "/media2/sda1/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/rootfs.ubifs";
    }
    else if(!(system("ls /media/sda/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/")))
    {
        path_argv[0] = "/media/sda/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/rootfs.ubifs";
    }
    else if(!(system("ls /media/sda1/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/")))
    {
        path_argv[0] = "/media/sda1/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/rootfs.ubifs";
    }
    else
    {
        /* Normal Boot */
        dw_PkgAvailFlag &= ~(BB_PKG_AVAIL_MASK);
        b_flag = 0x01;
    }

    return b_flag;
}
```

If rootfs is available . I call a script which does the upgrading .

Can this be done in some better way  instead of using if..else condition and the systemcall.

Also I am facing another issue is when i am using `system` call i.e i cannot pass the `char * path_argv[0]` as an argument to `system` call. again i have to do is this

```
system("/media/sda1/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/UPGRADEBB_File.sh '/media/sda1/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/rootfs.ubifs'");
```

can some way i can pass the pointer without using the `execv` call as i dont want to create new process.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to have a look at the [`stat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) system call. It allows you to test for the existance of a certain file or directory.

---

You can use [`sprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) to "print" into a "string".

```
char cmd[1024] = ""; /* Make sure this buffer is large enough. */
sprintf(cmd, "/media/sda1/UPGRADE_FILES/BB/UPGRADEBB_File.sh '%s'", path_argv[0]);
int result = system(cmd);
```

Comment: +1 for `stat()` over `system("ls")`.  You could also loop over the entries in `/media` if that is how your distro identifies mounted removable devices.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer . how can i pass two argument in the above manner ?

Comment: Each parameter needs to match a specifiv conversion specifier (`'s'` for a C-"string") prefixed by at least a `'%'` in the format string. For details please see the man-page for `printf()` as linked above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492916/best-way-to-monitor-disk-mounts-in-linux-using-c suggests that one can get notified when a media is mounted. This could maybe be better than using hard coded paths.